# Ruby Version Incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think I've got a simple problem but I've spent hours searching for the answer. It's taken me a while to get the correct version of ruby installed and recognized when running `ruby -v` (it had previously been `v2.5.1`, but for some reason I still can't use the command `bundle install`. It tells me I've got the wrong version of ruby... but this doesn't appear to be true???

I am trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails repository to an EC2 instance.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

---

I have ran these commands from within my repository directory:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]

bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.5.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.3
```

**.bashrc** and **.bash_profile** have the following commands in them:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:~/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Available versions:

```
~/.rbenv/versions$ ls
2.5.3

irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.5.3"

rbenv version
2.5.3 (set by /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/version)

whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby 
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby 
/usr/lib/ruby 
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby 
/snap/bin/ruby.rake /snap/bin/ruby.bundle         
/snap/bin/ruby.gem 
/snap/bin/ruby.env 
/snap/bin/ruby.rdoc 
/snap/bin/ruby 
/snap/bin/ruby.irb 
/snap/bin/ruby.ri 
/usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
```

`gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.3 (2018-10-18 patchlevel 105) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "“gem" => "--no-document”"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin
     - ~/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local
```

Comment: `which bundle` might help explain this. Looks like you may have two of them.

Comment: `which bundle
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/bundle` - is all that comes up

Comment: Does `gem env` check out?

Comment: Added the `gem env` to my question, thanks for your help. I'm no expert but looks okay? Shows v2.5.3

Comment: Everything here is checking out, so if it's still pulling up the wrong bundler then either something's wrong with `rbenv`, which might mean reinstalling that, or there's some other Ruby on your system that's jumping in and taking control. Is the system Ruby 2.5.1?

Comment: running [`rbenv rehash`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash) might help, but that's usually just needed if it can't find a gem bin...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force an update to your Ruby version in the Gemfile.lock:

`bundle update --ruby` in the same folder as the Gemfile.

If that didn't work you could also try a:

`gem install bundler`

Making sure you're in a directory/project that is using ruby 2.5.3 (i.e double check with ruby -v).

Finally you can do a manual rbenv rehash to check it's up-to-date:

`rbenv rehash`